# How can I check via lshosts (or some other IBM LSF command) if a compute host has at least n CPUs available from a single socket?

Tags: lsf

In an IBM LSF compute environment (I am a former longtime UGE user), in order to avoid the NUMA effect I would like to submit jobs like so:-

bsub -n 8 -R "span[hosts=1] affinity[core(1):distribute=pack]"

...which makes sure that all 8 slots will originate from a single socket. If the 8 slots are spread across, say, 2 sockets, my runtimes can increase by 20~30%, which I really need to avoid, especially when jobs are expected to run for weeks at a time.

The above command works fine as-is, but how can I check which available systems meet my requirements *before* the job is submitted? In other words, I would like to issue my bsub with a specific host name (-m option), but I want to be sure the host can indeed accommodate 8 slots from a single socket. lshosts looks promising, but I cannot get it to reveal enough information. Is there another command that should be used?